# Dictionary comprehension using range() with step

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I'm trying to build a dictionary using a dictionary comprehension in Python 2.7. I want to use the range() function with a start and stop value as well as a step size as the looping variable. The code is the following:

```
{ i: i*2 for i in range(0, 50, 5) }
```

When I run this in my REPL I get the following output:

```
{0: 0, 35: 70, 5: 10, 40: 80, 10: 20, 45: 90, 15: 30, 20: 40, 25: 50, 30: 60}
```

As you can see the values are not in a ascending order as one may expect.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Dicts aren't ordered in 2.7. Upgrade to 3.6 or use an `collections.OrderedDict`.

Comment: Why do you care about the order? The keys and values are what matter in a dictionary.

Comment: agree with commentators abow, but main question why you use python 2.7?

Comment: @BrownBear some environments are restricted, such as adding a feature to legacy military software

Comment: @ti7 are you sure that it is one of the OP case?

Comment: Hi everyone, as @ti7 pointed out I'm restricted in my environment and therefore I cannot use Python 3. Believe me, I would love to upgrade.

Comment: @Barmar Of course you are right that I can just access values by their keys but I would like to have the dict ordered by the keys in order to more easily write it to a file.

Comment: How does this make it easier to write to a file?

Comment: Maybe you should post the code for the actual problem you're trying to solve, as this sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Python 2.7, you want to use [`xrange`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#xrange) instead of range and a [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) from tuples

- [`xrange`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#xrange) is a sequence, which avoids creating an intermediate `list` object
- [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)s (perhaps obviously) are a dictionary which preserves insertion ordering

```py
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> d = OrderedDict((i, i*2) for i in xrange(0, 50, 5))
>>> d
OrderedDict([(0, 0), (5, 10), (10, 20), (15, 30), (20, 40), (25, 50), (30, 60), (35, 70), (40, 80), (45, 90)])
>>> d[5]
10
```

However, as **@Barmar** notes, the order *does not matter* if you are simply looking up the values (how it's represented does not necessarily indicate that values in the same order are faster to look up because they are hashed before searching). I haven't tested it, but it's likely more performant to have an unordered (normal) `dict`, which should be an O(1) lookup.

Further, because of the trivial formula for the dict, you are likely even better simply calculating them at runtime!